# Помогите разобраться с функцией wp_signon

Tags: wordpress

Делаю по документации кастомную форму авторизации (https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_signon).

my_authentification.php:

```
<?php   $my_user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());  ?>
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="http://myreg_test_wordpress.loc/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/my_auth.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-title "><h2>Authorization Form:</h2></div>
    <label>Email: <br />
        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" /></label>
    <label>Password :<br />
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" /></label>
    <label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> Запомнить меня</label>
    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="Войти" />

    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/my-temp-page-edit/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
    <a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url').'/my-temp-page/' ?>"><div class="my_btn">Перейти на страницу регистрации</div></a>
</form>
```

my_auth.php:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php' );

if( is_user_logged_in() ) exit;

$my_user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());

$credentials = array();
$credentials['user_login'] = $_POST['log'];
$credentials['user_password'] = $_POST['pwd'];
$credentials['remember'] = true;

// авторизуем
$user = wp_signon( $credentials, false );

// в случае неуспешной авторизации, смотрим, что не так
if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
    echo $user->get_error_message();
}
echo'<pre>';var_dump($_POST);echo'</pre>';
```

var_dump показывает, что данные из $_POST верно передаются, но почему тогда не срабатывает редирект на указанную страницу?
Помогите разобраться

Comment: Не разбирался "почему не срабатывает", но такой my_auth.php фтопку. а) 2я строка тупо опасна неработоспособностью сайта при изменении каталога  плагинов/тем . б) так принимать пост-запросы - это дырыща.

Comment: @SeVlad, полностью с Вами согласен... нашел решение проблемы

Answer (score 0):

Вот к такому решению моего вопроса я пришел.
my_authentification.php:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['log'])) {

    $user = wp_signon();

    if (is_wp_error($user)) {
    $auth_error = 'Wrong auth data';
    } else {
        // DON'T war_dumping !!!!!!!!
    wp_redirect('/my-temp-page-edit');
    exit;
    }

    };
    get_header();
    ?>
    <?php   $my_user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());  ?>
    <?php if (!$my_user->ID)  { ?>
        <form name="loginform" id="loginform"  method="post">
            <div class="form-title "><h2>Authorization Form: <span><?php echo $auth_error ?></span></h2></div>
            <label>Email: <br />
                <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" /></label>
            <label>Password :<br />
                <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" /></label>
            <label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> Remember me</label>
            <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="Enter" />

            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/my-temp-page-edit/" />
            <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
        </form>
    <?php  } ?>
```